# Deny access to a folder using .htaccess from web

Tags: .htaccess

I want to deny access to a folder from web using .htaccess, but I want give access to this folder inside the system.

I used `deny from all` in .htaccess file, it prevent the full access to the folder but I can't access the folder inside the system.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use allow and specify the adress to be allowed

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: It even allow me see the folders and files through web

Comment: yes if you allow your own provider ip adress in the .htaccess,
google 'myip' to find it.

Comment: Yes I know, but I want to know if there is any way to deny access through web. I.e, if I have a folder called system and inside this folder I have a file called config.conf. I want to deny the access to this folder through web, i.e: http://localhost/system or http://localhost/system/config.conf get deny. But if I need access to the file config.conf inside the system how can I do it? @jérôme-teisseire